# In Sublime Text, is there a way to get the Jinja2 package to automatically provide syntax support for files with the .html extension?

Tags: python, jinja2, sublimetext3

I would like for the Jinja2 package's syntax support to be provided automatically to files with the `.html` extension, given that the appropriate delimiters (`{% .. %}`, `{{ .. }}`) are detected.

I understand this would work for files with the `.j2` extension. I am asking if it could be applied to plain HTML files that include Jinja2 syntax, without having to add the entire `.html` file type (which would then apply it to any HTML file)?

For now, I have been selecting the `HTML (Jinja2)` option from the syntax definition dropdown menu for each file, obviously not an ideal solution.

Comment: Highlights are based on extensions, typically, not content. Otherwise, the whole file would need processed, and therefore slows the editor

Comment: @OneCricketeer, this is actually quite easy to do in Sublime. See below.

Comment: @Matt Your answer is still based on the extension, as I said. Question appeared to be asking to detect content of file

Comment: @OneCricketeer I mentioned writing a plugin, which would asynchronously search every new HTML file opened and change the syntax as soon as it came across `{{.*}}`. It's less than 10 lines long. Since opened files are already indexed by default in Sublime, the search should run very quickly, and because it runs async it's not blocking. I can add it into the answer if you're interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to open a `.html` file, then select **`View → Syntax → Open all with current extension as… → HTML (Jinja2)`**. This *should* do the trick. If not, there's a different way that involves writing a plugin, but this should be sufficient.

This still works based on the file's extension. However, highlighting of non-template content should be exactly the same as if you were using the regular HTML syntax.